# Show that $f(x, y, z) = xy + z^2$ is continuous. $(\varepsilon, \delta)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

> Show that $f: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$ $$f(x, y, z) = xy + z^2$$ is continuous.

One could just deduce that since it's a polynomial it's continuous, but how would I show this using $(\varepsilon, \delta)$? I'm not familiar on using the method with multivariate functions.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried choosing arbitrary $x_0, y_0, z_0 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and then manipulating $|f(x, y, z) - f(x_0, y_0, z_0)|$, but without luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $(x,y,z),(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in\Bbb R^3$, then\begin{align}\bigl|f(x,y,z)-f(x_0,y_0,z_0)\bigr|&=|xy-x_0y_0+z^2-z_0^{\,2}|\\&\leqslant|xy-x_0y_0|+|z^2-z_0^{\,2}|\\&=\bigl|(x-x_0)y_0+(y-y_0)x_0+(x-x_0)(y-y_0)\bigr|+\\&\phantom{=}+\bigl|(z-z_0)(z+z_0)\bigr|\\&\leqslant|x-x_0||y_0|+|y-y_0||x_0|+|x-x_0||y-y_0|+\\&\phantom{=}+|z-z_0|\bigl(|z-z_0|+2|z_0|\bigr).\end{align}So, given $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta>0$ such that:

- $\delta|y_0|<\dfrac\varepsilon5$;
- $\delta|x_0|<\dfrac\varepsilon5$;
- $\displaystyle\delta<\frac{\sqrt\varepsilon}{\sqrt5}$;
- $2\delta|z_0|<\dfrac\varepsilon5$.

Then, assuming that $|x-x_0|,|y-y_0|,|z-z_0|<\delta$, since $\bigl|f(x,y,z)-f(x_0,y_0,z_0)\bigr|$ is smaller than or equal to$$\overbrace{|x-x_0||y_0|}^{\phantom{\varepsilon/5}<\varepsilon/5}+\overbrace{|y-y_0||x_0|}^{\phantom{\varepsilon/5}<\varepsilon/5}+\overbrace{|x-x_0||y-y_0|}^{\phantom{\varepsilon/5}<\varepsilon/5}+\overbrace{|z-z_0|^2}^{\phantom{\varepsilon/5}<\varepsilon/5}+\overbrace{2|z-z_0||z_0|}^{\phantom{\varepsilon/5}<\varepsilon/5},$$you have$$\bigl|f(x,y,z)-f(x_0,y_0,z_0)\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: What's the intuition behind representing $|xy - x_0y_0| + |z^2- z^2_0|$ as $|(x-x_0)y_0 + (y-y_0)x_0 + (x-x_0)(y-y_0)| + |(z-z_0)(z+z_0)|$?

Comment: You can force the numbers $x-x_0$, $y-y_0$ and $z-z_0$ to be as small as you like. So, you write $xy+z^2-\left(x_0y_0+z_0^{\,2}\right)$ as a function of those threee numbers. This will help you to make $xy+z^2-\left(x_0y_0+z_0^{\,2}\right)$ small.

Comment: I see. From here I would need to find appropriate $\delta$ in order to make this work(?). However the expression I'm left with doesn't seem to be in the form that this would be achieved easily. Could I use some kind of substitution here?

Comment: I have completed the proof. Is it clear?

Comment: It is clear. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Denote $\xi = (x,y,z)$ and $\alpha = (a,b,c)$. Then,
\begin{align}
|f(\xi) - f(\alpha)| &= |(xy+z^2) - (ab+c^2)|\\
&= |(x-a)y + a(y-b) + (z-c)(z+c)|\\
& \leq |y| |x-a| + |a||y-b| + |z+c| |z-c| \\
&\leq \left( |y| + |a| + |z+c|\right) \lVert\xi - \alpha \rVert
\end{align}
Now, if $\lVert \xi-\alpha\rVert < 1$, can you find an upper bound on the thing in brackets?

If this is still too far of a leap, I suggest you take a look at the proof of how we prove the sums and product of continuous functions is continuous. In particular look at the proof of why $t\mapsto t^2$ is continuous from single-variable analysis.

---

Notice that the idea is to use basic algebra and "force" terms like $x-a$ to appear, because if this is small enough, you can make the entire thing small enough.